# JAX-RS: Providing a "default" Sub-resource locator

Tags: java, regex, rest, jax-rs, restlet

I am using JAX-RS to develop a RESTful API. A simplified version of my API is as follows:

```
GET /appapi/v1.0/users
POST /appapi/v1.1/users

... ... and so on
```

As you can see, the pattern follows `{api_name}/v{major_version}.{minor_version}/{rest_of_the_path}`.

I have an additional requirement:

> **If the version is not specified, then the latest version should be used by default** - i.e.,

`GET /appapi/users` should be equivalent to `GET /appapi/v1.1/users` (assuming 1.1 is the latest version of users).

This is how I have implemented this using JAX RS.

```
@Path("/appapi")
public class AppApiRootResource {

    @Path("/{version: [v]\\d+[[.]\\d+]?}/")
    public AppApiSubResource getVersionedSubResource
                            (@PathParam("version") String version){
        System.out.println("Version: "+version);
        String versionString = version.substring(1); //Discard the leading 'v'
        String majorVersion = "";
        String minorVersion = "0";
        if(versionString.contains(".")){
            String [] splits = versionString.split(".");
            majorVersion = splits[0];
            minorVersion = splits[1];
        } else {
            majorVersion = versionString;
        }

        return SubResourceFactory.getSubResource(majorVersion, minorVersion);

    }

    @Path("/{^([v]\\d+[[.]\\d+]?)}/") //Is This Correct??
    public AppApiSubResource getDefaultApiResource(){
        /*
         * Need help defining the regular expression here 
         * so that this is used for anything that doesn't match
         * the "version" regexp above
         */
        System.out.println("API version not specified; Using default version");
        return SubResourceFactory.getLatestVersionSubResource();
    }
}
```

My Sub-Resource class is defined as follows. I have sub-classes of this class to deal with multiple versions of the API.
The implementation of `SubResourceFactory` is not relevant for the purposes of this discussion. It just returns an instance of `AppApiSubResource` or its sub-class

```
public class AppApiSubResource {


    /**
     * Create a new user
     */
    @POST
    @Path("users")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response createUser(String newUser, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path("10")).build();       
        return Response.created(uri).build();
    }

    /**
     * Get a user
     */
    @GET
    @Path("users/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") String userId
            ) {

        return Response.ok().entity("<user></user>").build();
    }
}
```

> **Problem statement:**
>
> - If I comment out `getDefaultApiResource()`, then things work as expected when there is a version specifier in the API. However, if I un-comment `getDefaultApiResource()`,  it is always being invoked, irrespective of whether I have the v1.0 in the request or not.
> - Also, if I un-comment `getDefaultApiResource()`, I get a 404 when I do a `GET /appapi/users` (i.e, without the version specifier); but things work fine if I use `GET /appapi/v1.0/users` (i.e., with a version specifier)

So, how do I set up my sub-resource locator paths/regexps such that the method is invoked when there is no version specifier in the request?

I'm using Restlet framework, but this question is implementation-agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason getDefaultApiResource always gets invoked is that its URI pattern is the same regular expression as that of getVersionedSubResource, and when more than one pattern matches the request URI, the longest pattern (literally, the one with the most characters) wins.  ("version: " is not considered part of the pattern.)  See section 3.7.2 of the [JAX-RS specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-1.1-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/) for all the details.

I've never tried this, but I think @Path("") will do what you want.

By the way, it appears your regular expression isn't quite right:

```
[v]\\d+[[.]\\d+]?
```

That says "lowercase v, followed by one or more digits, optionally followed by a single period, digit, or plus sign."  It should be:

```
[v]\\d+([.]\\d+)?
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm new to regular expressions. I was under the assumption that the regexp for `getDefaultApiResource()` is the __negation__ of that for `getVersionedSubResource()` since I started it with the `^`. Isn't that true? I will try your other suggestions.

Comment: Your suggestion of using `@Path("")` worked. Anything that doesn't match the `getVersionedSubResource` "falls back" to the one annotated with `@Path("")`. I had to make some (temporary) changes to the regex. Restlet throws some weird `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I use `[v]\\d+([.]\\d+)?`. I replaced it with `[v]\\d+[.]\\d+` (basically, I'm mandating the version specifier to have both a major and a minor version, dot-separated). Things are working fine now.